# Actionscript services stop functioning

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have built a complex AIR application which has been successfully running for quite some time of many PCs.  Unfortunately, I have a plaguing problem with internet connectivity and I was wondering if anyone had encountered this issue before.

Every once in a while, the program will completely stop talking to the internet (all services start faulting).  I wrote special code in my program to monitor the situation in which I use two different services to contact the same server.

The first service:

```
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("myURL.com");
this.urlMonitor = new URLMonitor(req, [200, 304]); // Acceptable status codes
this.urlMonitor.pollInterval = 60 * 1000; // Every minute
this.urlMonitor.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, onStatusChange);
this.urlMonitor.start();

private function onStatusChange(e:StatusEvent):void 
{
        if (this.urlMonitor.available)
        {
            pollStatusOnline = true;
            Online = true;
        }
        else
        {
            pollStatusOnline = false;
            Online = false;
        }  
}
```

The secondary method is a normal HTTP Service call:

```
checkInService = new HTTPService();
checkInService.method = "POST";
checkInService.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT,sendResult);
checkInService.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, faultResult);
checkInService.addEventListener(InvokeEvent.INVOKE, invokeAttempt);
checkInService.url = "myURL.com";
checkInService.concurrency = Concurrency.LAST;
checkInService.send(params);
```

These two services point to the same location and work 98% of the time.  Sometimes, after a few hours, I have noticed that both services no longer can connect to the website.  The HTTP Service returns a StatusCode 0.  I am able to open command prompt and ping the server directly with no problem from the PC which is failing.  The services will not function again until the program is restarted.

I have been working on this issue for many months now without resolution.  If anyone is able to even point me in a somewhat possible, maybe this might be the problem, possibly, direction, I would really appreciate it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `code` value of the `StatusEvent` you receive from the `URLMonitor` - this might give more info than the `HTTPService` (you might also want to try passing a `null` value to `URLMonitor` constructor, to widen the acceptable status codes).

If you have access to the server(s?) in question, check their logs. Could the server config have changed such that it might now consider such frequent requests as flooding?

You should also be able to use an HTTP debugger like Fiddler or Charles on the client machine to see more information about the requests going out of your application.